# Backward slash before command substitution in shell variable assignment

Tags: bash, function, shell

I want to display the current working branch in the prompt as below:

```
f() { echo -n $(awk -F/ '{print $3}' <(git symbolic-ref HEAD));};  PS1="\$(f) $ "
```

If I remove the backward slash character before the function call command substitution in the PS1 assignment, then during changes of git branch the function is **NOT** invoked duly. Only if backward slash is present then I get the expected behavior. I wonder how this "\" makes the function call appropriately?

Also, the below direct assignment to PS1 variable is not updating the prompt string when changing the branch, even here the \ is present.

```
export PS1="\$(awk -F/ '{print $3}' <<< `git symbolic-ref HEAD`) $ "
```

Let me know how to correct it.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `echo -n`, just `printf` in `awk` to print without newline:

```
f() { awk -F/ '{printf "%s", $3}' <(git symbolic-ref HEAD); }
```

Then use it in `PS1` as:

```
PS1='$(f) $ '
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip on awk printf, but your code does not update branch label when branch is changed (due to missing \ char)

Comment: `f() { awk -F/ '{printf $3}' <(git symbolic-ref HEAD);};  PS1="\$(f) $ "` is my code

Comment: Right that is what I suggested in my answer but what git command are you using to see that `PS1` doesn't update it.

Comment: I use the git command `git branch`. I got the problem, the single quotes and double quotes makes the difference

Comment: No, double quote is not needed. This solution is working **as is** for me. After I execute `git checkout branch1` command in my shell, my prompt immediately changes to `branch1 $`